# React Native custom iOS view that responds to height/width style

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm trying to get my custom UIView to respond to width and height styles, e.g.

```
<MyCustomView style={{width: 200, height: 300}}/>
```

I've closely followed the simple example at https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-dashed-border-example

Currently my View and ViewManager look like:

```
#import "MyCustomView.h"
#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@implementation MyCustomView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
      // Create the component view
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

and the ViewManager:

```
@implementation MyCustomViewManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}

@end
```

However this of course always fills the screen. I want to be able to set the height on this component, and ideally using the RN method of passing it via `style`.

If I follow the simple border example, I end up with

```
@implementation MyCustomView

- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
      // Create the component view
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

and

```
@implementation MyCustomViewManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
}

@end
```

But the view does not show, and reports `self.bounds.size.height` to be 0.00.

Is there something I've missed to get this working? Do I need to employ RCTBridge? I did previously have the line

```
@synthesize bridge = _bridge;
```

as in https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-dashed-border-example/blob/master/BVDashedBorderViewManager.m#L9 but I got an error saying "Bridge not set"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override reactSetFrame in your view and you'll get access to the frame whenever it's updated by a React Native layout:

```
- (void)reactSetFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    CGFloat height = frame.size.height;
    // Do something with the height here
    [super reactSetFrame: frame];
}
```

You'll need to import the React category for UIView if you're not already for that file:

```
#import "UIView+React.h"
```

Comment: I also had to `#import "UIView+React.h"`

Comment: Thanks! I'll add that in